# Angular UI typeahead model changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a strange situation with ui typeahead. For some reason when results come the **ng-model** is changed to first result of results. That is problem to me because I have on-enter event in which I need to use value from input.

Here is HTML:

```
<input type="search" dropdown-toggle
                               class="form-control input--search"
                               pw-enter="searchEnter()"
                               placeholder="Search"
                               typeahead="result.text for result in getSearchResult($viewValue)"
                               ng-model="search.query"
                               typeahead-template-url="views/search-custom.html"
                               typeahead-wait-ms="300"
                               typeahead-focus-first="false"
                               >
```

Code:

```
$scope.getSearchResult = function (query) {
            return SearchService.getResults(query);
        };

$scope.searchEnter = function(){
            $location.path('/advance-search').search({query : $scope.search.query});
        };
```

As you can see it is search implementation and **on-enter** I need to go to advance search with value that is searched (**$scope.search.query**) but for some reason that value is changed to **first** result in results as I mentioned.

How can I fix this or is there any workaround?

Comment: There is
"typeahead-focus-first (Defaults: true) : Should the first match automatically be focused as you type?" in [official documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), does false value help in your case?

Comment: and also why do you not use 
"typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label)" for advanced search, but use custom directive "pwEnter"?